# PyCharm: Navigate to recent method?

Tags: python, pycharm

I like the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> "recent files" dialog of PyCharm and use it often.

Is there a way to list the recent **methods** I visited during the last minutes too?

Comment: I guess that that there isn't any "recent file". If there is by **SHIFT + CTRL + A** and type `recent` you should find it....

Comment: @Micheled'Amico there is a recent files dialog (ctrl e). But I am missing a recent **methods** dialog.

Comment: Sorry... I meant *there isn't any "recent method"* instead

Answer (score 6):

You can go to the last visited method with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> (left arrow) and again to the next last, but i have no idea how to show a list of them.

Comment: I use the alt+left shortcut, too. But sometimes a list like in "recent files" would be nice.

Answer (score 3):

As others have stated, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd> navigates back in time. As for all the other useful shortcuts, there are two  reference cards available for PyCharm's default keymap:

1. [for Windows/Unix](https://resources.jetbrains.com/assets/products/pycharm/PyCharm_ReferenceCard.pdf)
2. [for Mac](https://resources.jetbrains.com/assets/products/pycharm/PyCharm_ReferenceCard_mac.pdf)

Jetbrains will send you these as high quality flyers if you call their marketing department and ask nicely ;-)
Here is a little extract of the navigation section:

[image: ref]

Unfortunately, 
For those who are using the eclipse keymap or sth. entirely different, there is no such comprehensive reference.

Comment: By the way, any one can obtain the default keymap cheatsheet as pdf from the PyCharm IDE itself : **"Help -> Default KeyMap Reference"**